# external axis of rotation and moment of inertia

Tags: moment-of-inertia

I have a rigid disk rotating around an external axis of rotation ( not even touching the disk ) , i tried to draw roughly the figure . The disk is not rotating around itself only the vertical axis passing through A . So what is the moment of inertia of the disk with respect to axis of rotation passing A ??

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a disc rotating around a single axis.

Rather you have a collection of individual points, all fixed relative to one another, ***in both distance and relative direction***.  Each point is moving in its own circle about a different axis; all the circles have the same radius.

The moment of inertia of a point mass is simple;  moments of inertia for a collection of points are additive.